# Plot with ScalingFunctions->{"Infinite",interval}

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Consider the plot

[image]

The X-axis presents a log-scale, left-extended from Zero and right-extended to Infinity, with focus on the interval `{2,50}`. It conveys the information that the functions are 0 at the origin and tend asymptotically to 1.

**Q:** Is there a way to change the "focused interval" from `{2,50}` to something else, like `{.001,5}`?

---

I would like to draw a plot with logarithmic scale on the X-axis, and linear scale on the Y-axis; the X-axis going to Infinity, while focusing on a specific interval.

Consulting the documentation of [Plot/Options/ScalingFunctions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), I found out that `ScalingFunctions->{"OptA","OptB"}`
would apply `"OptA"` scaling to the X-axis and `"OptB"` to the Y-axis.

Consulting the documentation of [ScalingFunctions/Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html), I figured the option
`{"Infinite",interval}`, to

> show asymptotic behavior by compressing infinite ranges into finite ranges

by setting an

> infinite scale focused on *interval*

was what I was looking for my X-axis.

I tried

```
Plot[{F[.25, 0, t], F[.25, .1, t], F[.25, .2, t]}, {t,0, Infinity}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {{"Infinite", {.001, 50}}, None}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a=0", "a=0.1", "a=0.2"}, {.9, .3}]]
```

which yielded the output shown in the above image.

---

Function:

```
lam[pi2_] := 1/(2 pi2 - 1);
gama[pi2_, a_, t_] := 1 - Exp[lam[pi2]*t] + 2 lam[pi2]^2*t*(pi2 - a)*Exp[lam[pi2]*t];
F[pi2_, a_, t_] := pi2 (1 - pi2)/(pi2 - Exp[lam[pi2]*t] (pi2 - a))/
  (1 - pi2 + Exp[lam[pi2]*t] (pi2 - a))*gama[pi2, a, t]^2
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the definition of `F` (mismatched parentheses/brackets). Edit your question to correct this.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for spotting that. Corrected it. When I copy paste the code from WM to this SE, it introduces extra line breaks, is there a better way to copy paste long lines? Thx

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

lam[pi2_] := 1/(2 pi2 - 1);
gama[pi2_, a_, t_] := 
  1 - Exp[lam[pi2]*t] + 2 lam[pi2]^2*t*(pi2 - a)*Exp[lam[pi2]*t];
F[pi2_, a_, t_] := 
 pi2 (1 - pi2)/(pi2 - Exp[lam[pi2]*t] (pi2 - a))/(1 - pi2 + 
     Exp[lam[pi2]*t] (pi2 - a))*gama[pi2, a, t]^2
```

Using [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html)

```
Plot[Evaluate[F[.25, #, t] & /@ {{0, 0.1, 0.2}}],
 {t, 0, Infinity},
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.5},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a=0", "a=0.1", "a=0.2"}, {.9, .85}],
 Epilog -> Inset[
   LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[F[.25, #, t] & /@ {{0, 0.1, 0.2}}],
    {t, 0.01, 5},
    PlotRange -> {0, 1.5},
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   {.5, .495}],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I don't know how to do what you want. However, if your primary interest is the interval `{0.001, 5}` use either

```
a = {0, 1/10, 1/5};

funcs = (F[1/4, #, t] & /@ a) // Simplify;

plt = Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip /@ funcs],
  {t, 0, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1.5}},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[N@a,
     LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[a], 14]], {.9, .3}],
  GridLines -> {None, {1}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.75], Gray, Dashed]]
```

[image]

```
plt = LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[Tooltip /@ funcs],
  {t, 0.001, 5},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.5},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[N@a,
     LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[a], 14]], {.9, .3}],
  GridLines -> {None, {1}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.75], Gray, Dashed]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. Also thanks for the `Evaluate[F[.25, #, t] & /@ {{0, 0.1, 0.2}}]` trick, it was on my To-look-next list.

Comment: The first Plot is already close to what I am looking for: the X-axis presents a log-scale, left-extended from Zero and right-extended to Infinity, with focus on the interval `{2,50}`. **Q:** Isn't there a way to change the "focused interval" from `{2,50}` to something else, like `{.001,5}`? I am new to WM but I feel it must be doable...

Comment: Is plotting to `Infinity` a new feature in `v13`?

Comment: @Syed - Yes it is new in v13

Comment: For posterity: Applying the Edit in v13.0.1, the left padding on the X-axis [was not working well](https://imgur.com/Bsaw7LL). A possible workaround is to drop `PlotRangePadding` and manually pad with `PlotRange -> {{.0006, 8}, {0, 1.6}}`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need scaling functions for this. For the most common cases there are ready made functions. For your case , you would want: "LogLinearPlot".

Then I do not get the same plot as you. For t->Infiniy the functions -> zero.

Further, if the x axis is logarithmic, it can not start at zero, because this is at infinity.

Here is a plot of your functions from 10^-2 to 5:

```
M1 = LogLinearPlot[{F[.35, 0, t], F[.25, .1, t], F[.25, .2, t]}, {t, 
   10^-2, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"a=0", "a=0.1", "a=0.2"}, {.9, .7}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. 1) I had an typo in the formula of F (copy pasting introduces line breaks, and I erased a `]` in the correction process). 2) I also wanted `F[.25, 0, t]` in the plot. But these do not affect the essence of the question.

Comment: I would like to show the plot from 0.01 to 5, between Zero and Infinity, where is now shown from 2 to 50. Alternatively, is there a way to extend the X-axis in the `LogLinearPlot` from Zero and to Infinity, similarly to what the plot is doing? I would like to convey that the functions come from 0 and go to 1.

Comment: I do not understand: "I would like to show the plot from 0.01 to 5, between Zero and Infinity, where is now shown from 2 to 50". I made you a plot  from 0.01 to 5. On a log. axis it is not possible to plot from zero. However, you can plot x->infinity. Your functions are zero at x==0 but go to zero at x->Infinity. Simply change the specification of "t".

Comment: I was referring to the Plot in the question. The X-axis presents a log-scale, left-extended from Zero and right-extended to Infinity, with focus on the interval `{2,50}`.
**Q:** Is there a way to change the "focused interval" from `{2,50}` to something else, like `{.001,5}`?

Comment: I think I did this in my answer. Note, the original axis from 0 to infinity is NOT a log axis because 0 can not be displayed in a log axis.

Comment: Infinity cannot be displayed in a log axis (or any axis, for the matter) also. Unless *by extension* as in the question's Plot. Your answer is almost there, if only we can find how to extend it from Zero/to Infinity. The question almost does it also, but is 'decentralized'.

Comment: O.K. this can only be done with scaling functions.  As a start, look at:  `Plot[{F[.35, 0, t], F[.25, .1, t], F[.25, .2, t]}, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> {{ArcTan, Tan}, "Linear"}]`